# What does "x" mean in "for x in range(10):"?

Tags: python

I'm curious what `x` means when you look at this:

```
import random

for x in range(10):
    print random.randint(1,101)
```

Comment: It's a variable name. What don't you understand exactly?

Answer (score 2):

`x` itself has no special meaning, it simply (as a part of the `for` loop) provides a way to repeat

```
print random.randint(1,101)
```

10 times, regardless of the variable name (i.e., `x` could be, say, `n`).

In each iteration the value of `x` keeps increasing, but we don't use it. On the other hand, e.g.,

```
for x in range(3):
    print(x)
```

would give

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: would the output be the same if i replaced "x" with "n"?

Comment: Yes, and traditionally one would use `_` as the variable name here to make it clear that it's not actually used.

Answer (score 0):

X is a variable name, so could be any name allowed by python for variable names. As a variable , it’s value will be different every time the loop circle ends, in this particular loop range(10) the value of x will start in 0 and next 1 , and next 2, until reach value of 10

so If you want to print a random int:

```
for x in range(10):
    print(random.randint(x))
```

also, if it is python3.X, `print(x)` not `print x`, second is python2.X

Comment: so would i have to print(x) to get the output?

Comment: @JohnDoe exactly

Answer (score 0):

For x in range(3) simply means,
for each value of x in range(3), range(3) = 0,1,2

As it is range(3), the loop is looped three times and at each time, value of x becomes 0, then 1 and then 2

Answer (score 0):

Here, x is just a variable name used to store the integer value of the current position in the range of loop and it iterates through out the range of a loop.

Like in for x in range(10):

x iterates 10 times and for instance in your for loop above, during the first iteration of the loop x = 1, then x=2 for the next iteration then, x= 3 and so on...

It is not neccessary to take x as a variable only you can take any variable name like i,a etc...

Answer (score 0):

I am coming from a short intro in C, and I was confused by the 'x' as well. For those coming from C,C++,C# etc.:

The 'x in range(10)' is the same thing as doing this in C:

for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)